# Get user email without full permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I need to get the email of the user accessing the web app. The web app is embedded in a google site. 
I know how to do that with the following:

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

However, that requires that the user grant permission to the script and the permission message is quite scary: it allows to send email on the user behalf, modify any of his/her google sheets, and so on.

Is there a way to avoid that wide range of permissions just to get the user email?

Update: my script also need to update a sheet, but does not have to be updated by the user. However, I need the user to run the app themself to get their email.

Comment: Well, of course it does - after all, your application seems to perform much more on user's behlaf than just request access to email (you probably have `SpreadsheetApp` and `GmailApp` / `MailApp` used). The only scope needed for `getActiveUser()` is `userinfo.email`. Unless you **deploy your app to "run as me"**, you have to tell your users all the info they need to make conscious decision to trust your application (or not). Just remember that by doing so, the app will act on your behalf and use your quotas

Comment: Depending upon what you're doing you might be able to utilize more limited scopes by manually editing your appsscript.json file.  But you probably won't remove all of the scary permission warnings.

Comment: you are actually right, I also need to update a sheet based on a selection (but I am ok to write back to the sheet as me and not as the user). No email sent though. So the only reason why I need to run the script as the user and not as me, is just to get their email (so that I can show only few info based on who they are)

Answer (score 2):

The permissions referred in the question

> it allows to send email on the user behalf, modify any of his/her google sheets, and so on.

aren't related to

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser the above method only requires

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

If you want a less "scary" permissions you should have to remove the methods that require them or set the oAuth scopes manually in the manifest and/or th oAuth consent page of your project.

Comment: I see. I actually also need to update a sheet based on a selection. But I could do with my account. The only reason I need the user to run the app (and not run as me), is just to know who they are so that I can show less info. Maybe I could do 2 web-app embedded in the site and have the user to run as user only the part which get their email? It is quite complicated though for a beginner like me.

Comment: If you want to request the minimum and lowest level permissions you have to split your project in two or more depending on how many sets of permissions are required.